# Substring syntaxes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Python has the following elegant syntax for checking whether one string is a substring of another one:

```
'ab' in 'abc' # True
```

Is there an equivalent elegant syntax in Ruby?

I'm aware to the `"abc".includes? "ab"` Ruby syntax, but I'm wondering whether the inverse syntax exists too (where the first parameter is the substring and the second is the string).

Comment: IIRC there isn't one by default, but it's a line or two on the String class, no?

Comment: I wonder why toro2k's answer was deleted. That is the only correct answer so far.

Comment: Because the OP already knew about `include?` and ruled it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't such method in Ruby standard library, but <del>Rails</del> ActiveSupport provides `#.in?` method:

```
1.9.3-p484 :004 > "ab".in? "abc"
 => true
```

Here is the source code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e20dd73df42d63b206d221e2258cc6dc7b1e6068/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion.rb

Comment: Not Rails but ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 4):

Define "elegant".

This does a sub-string search and returns the "hit" if found:

```
'abc'['ab'] # => "ab"
```

Using `!!` converts the value returned to a true/false, so `"ab"` becomes true:

```
!!'abc'['ab'] # => true
```

Knowing that, it's trivial to add it in if you want something closer:

```
class String
  def in?(other)
    !!other[self]
  end
end

'ab'.in?('abc') # => true
'ab'.in? 'abc' # => true
```

Or, use `require 'active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion'` to cherry-pick the Active Suport definition that extends all objects to allow `in?`. See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#in-questionmark. The upside/downside to that it's modifying all objects.